# Custom ViewCell Bindable Properties does not work

Tags: uitableview, xaml, xamarin.forms

I created ViewCell (custom EntryCell) for TableView, but the value does not bind to my ViewModel. 
If i create default EntryCell, then all works fine, but my custom ViewCell does not bind.

[image]

I just can not understand what's wrong, I really hope for your help

**EntryCell.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="AproReportsClient.UI.Controls.EntryCell"
          x:Name="This"
          BindingContext="{x:Reference This}">

    <Entry Text="{Binding Text}"
           Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder}"         
           TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
           FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Margin="12, 8, 8, 8"
           HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

</ViewCell>
```

**EntryCell.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace AproReportsClient.UI.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class EntryCell : ViewCell
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(Placeholder),
                                    returnType:   typeof(string),
                                    declaringType:typeof(EntryCell),
                                    defaultValue: string.Empty);

        public string Placeholder
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty);
            set => SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value);
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(Text),
                                    returnType:   typeof(string),
                                    declaringType:typeof(EntryCell),
                                    defaultValue: string.Empty);

        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty TextColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(TextColor),
                                    returnType:   typeof(Color),
                                    declaringType:typeof(EntryCell),
                                    defaultValue: Color.Black);

        public Color TextColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(TextColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextColorProperty, value);
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(FontSize),
                                    returnType:   typeof(double),
                                    declaringType:typeof(EntryCell),
                                    defaultValue: 10d);

        public double FontSize
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
            set => SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
        }


        public EntryCell ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

**Page:**

```
//....

<TableView Grid.Row="1" 
                       HasUnevenRows="True">
                <TableRoot>
                    <TableSection>
                        <EntryCell Text="{Binding Title}"/>

                        <controls:EntryCell Placeholder="{extensions:Translate Title}"
                                            Text="{Binding Title}"
                                            TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                                            FontSize="{StaticResource HeaderFontSize}"/>
                    </TableSection>

                    <TableSection Title="{extensions:Translate AdditionalFields}">
                        <controls:EmptyCell EmptyHeight="150"/>
                    </TableSection>
                </TableRoot>
            </TableView>

//....
```

I also checked in the TextChanged event handler that the text property is null . There is no set, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your BindingContext in your Cell constructor.

```
 public EntryCell ()
 {
      InitializeComponent ();
      BindingContext = this;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help. The Get method is always executed in properties, but Set is not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is a problem with property binding in ViewCell. Someone can create a new CustomEntryCell which extends the XF EntryCell. The OnAppearing should be overriden in this class. In the OnAppearing method the EntryCell's properties can be filed with BindedContext. BindedContext is your object which contains Title.